# Displaying 3d objects without iFrames

Tags: javascript, three.js, model-viewer

I have a database where users can upload their 3d models and currently there is a functioning App wherein the users can view their 3d models. But in order to embed those 3d models onto their website, I am currently using an IFrame. What are the alternatives to this?

I have come across this website(CGTrader Arsenal) called where in they are hosting a javascript file as a library and then using it to display their models.

[image]

How can I implement something similar? How can a standalone javascript talk to the database and get the required information? Also how one one return the 3d model back to the browser to be drawn?

Comment: There are many 3D engines for the web: three.js, babylon.js, playcanvas, ... none of them require IFrames, and none will load anything _directly_ from most databases: you'll need a server or static hosting to send the 3D model data in response to an HTTP Request, like `mysite.com/models/<model-id>.glb`. If you're not sure how to do that you may want to open a new question with details about your database and/or server.

Comment: Assuming that I have a functioning server, how would I embed this specific 3dmodel on a client website. Because the client can have a functioning page with various images/videos/text. And the only insertion that needs to be done on the webpage is the 3d model.

Comment: One simple option would be something like https://modelviewer.dev/; you just need a URL that will serve the model. But there are dozens of WebGL libraries to choose from, and most have their own documentation about how to load and display models in various formats.